# Conditional step in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, conditional-statements

I have the following situation:

```
.
.
.
stage('My stage')
{
  steps
  {
    sh 'my_command1.sh'
    sh 'my_command2.sh'
    sh 'my_command3.sh'
  }
}
.
.
.
```

It is possible for example to execute the step "my_command2.sh" only if there is a particular condition? I know that it is possible to define conditional statement with "when" token, but the condition has an impact to all the stage. I want to limit this behavior only for a single step.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `script`
Then your stage will be like:

```
stage('My Stage') {
    steps {
       script{
           sh 'my_command1.sh'    
           if(condition){
               sh 'my_command2.sh'           
           }
           sh 'my_command3.sh'   
           }
        }
    }
```

You can also check declarative step from [official documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-steps)